# HTML Dynamic Input Box Based on Dropdown Selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Have a (hopefully) simple question where I want an input box to automatically appear based on a previous dropdown selection choice.

Pretty new to all this so any help is greatly appreciated!

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<legend><b>Did Cardio Session?</b></legend>
      <p>  
           <select name = "cardio" id = "cardio">
           <option value = "No" selected>No</option>
           <option value = "Yes">Yes</option>
           </select>

           <div id = "cardioyes" style = "display:none;">
           <label for="How Long?">How Long?</label>
           <input type = "text" name = "duration" />
           </div>
      </p>

      <script>
      $('#cardio').change(function(){
        selection = $(this).val();
        switch(selection)
        {
            //show the <div> or not
            case 'Yes':
                $('#cardioyes').show();
                break;
                default:
                $('#cardioyes').hide();
                break;
        }
      });
      </script>
```

Comment: You do have the code; what's the problem?

Comment: its working I guess, maybe you want the `input` to be updated when the page loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only things that could have gone wrong are

1. You are not loading jQuery library
2. You attempt to use the `.change` event handler before the element appears in code -- `$(document).ready` takes care of that.

Other than those, as you could see your code works:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cardio').change(function() {
    selection = $(this).val();
    switch (selection) {
      case 'Yes':
        $('#cardioyes').show();
        break;

      default:
        $('#cardioyes').hide();
        break;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<legend><b>Did Cardio Session?</b></legend>
<p>
  <select name="cardio" id="cardio">
    <option value = "No" selected>No</option>
    <option value = "Yes">Yes</option>
  </select>

  <div id="cardioyes" style="display:none;">
    <label for="How Long?">How Long?</label>
    <input type="text" name="duration" />
  </div>
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes adding the library fixed the issue: